# What is the best way to create a new column by grouping values?

Tags: python, dataframe, grouping

I'm trying to add a column to a table grouping values of one column to create a new column.

This is the code I've written.

```
df3['seasons']=np.nan

df3.loc[df3['month'] >= 1 & df3['month'] < 4,'seasons']='Winter'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df3['seasons']=np.nan
df3.loc[np.logical_and(df3['month'] >= 1, df3['month'] < 4),'seasons'] = 'Winter'
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain what your code does.